# Is there only one unique minimizer for this scalar complex quadratic form?

Tags: optimization, quadratic-forms, quadratic-programming

Consider $c,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f: \mathbb{C} \mapsto \mathbb{R}$, 
$$f(c) = bc' + b'c + cc'$$
is there only one extrema of $f$ corresponds to $$c^* = -b$$?
where, $'$ means complex conjugate.

### What I thought

since $df(c)/dc = b + b' + c + c' = 0$, therefore any $c \in \mathbb{C}$ such that $Re(b) + Re(c) = 0 $ will suffice. But I am very worried about what I thought which is so weird.

Comment: What do you mean by the prime character? Don't you have $bc'=c'b$?

Comment: @LinAlg sorry for the typo, it is $b'c$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writing $c=x + y i$, the hessian of your function is the identity matrix. Since that matrix is positive definite, the function is strictly convex in $x$ and $y$. It therefore only has one optimum.

Additionally writing $b=d+ei$, you get $f(c) = 2dx+2ey+x^2+y^2$. The derivative with respect to $x$ is $2d+2x$, so $x=d$ (this part you had). The derivative with respect to $y$ is $2e+2y$, so $y=e$ (this you did not have yet).

Comment: I see. when I using everything from $\mathbb{R}$, things are clear and no issues. It is interesting to see that $df/dc = 0$ somehow doesn't work in this case. Do you have any insight about this?

Comment: @Shaowu it works fine, but your derivative has an imaginary part that should be 0 as well, see my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks. I think the derivative I wrote down does have the imaginary part since `b` and `c` are complex numbers. I know that when breaking things to $\mathbb{R}$ works perfect but I just don't know how to get the imaginary part equation that constraints the solution to be unique, through a complex derivative way.